# Concept of services, tags, and arguments

Tags: 8, symfony-services

I defined a service using the following code.

```
services:
  redirect.repository:
    class: Drupal\redirect\RedirectRepository
    arguments: ['@entity.manager', '@database', '@config.factory']
    tags:
      - { name: backend_overridable }
```

According to my understanding, `'@entity.manager'` , `'@database'`, and `'@config.factory'` are classes on which *the service* is dependent.

Now, the entity.manager service definition is the following.

```
class: Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManager
parent: container.trait
tags:
  - { name: plugin_manager_cache_clear }
```

It has a tag associated with it. Maybe this tag manages all entity specific cache.

What is the responsibility of the redirect.repository services?
Does this service help communicating with the database directly?
What if I don't have any entity and I implemented `hook_schema()`? Can I mention my custom database table name instead of @entity.manager?
Where do these tags actually get registered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Database

`redirect.repository` communicates with the database through its usage of the class represented by the `database` service injected into its initialize method (`__construct`). However the RedirectRepository class does not itself use `PDO` to connect to the database.

The redirect module has chosen not to implement an entity to store its data, and is an example of using Drupal's database abstraction layer (DBAL) from the `database` service.

```
// Load redirects by hash. A direct query is used to improve performance.
$rid = $this->connection
  ->query('SELECT rid FROM {redirect} WHERE hash IN (:hashes[]) ORDER BY LENGTH(redirect_source__query) DESC', [':hashes[]' => $hashes])
  ->fetchField();
```

#### 2. Entity Manager

The `entity.manager` service provides a *deprecated* helper class to make it easier to get information about **entities** only. If you do not implement an entity, then you cannot use any of the entity-related services such as `entity.manager` or `entity_type.manager`.

#### 3. [Dependency Injection Tags](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/dic_tags.html)

> Dependency Injection Tags are little strings that can be applied to a
>   service to "flag" it to be used in some special way. For example, if
>   you have a service that you would like to register as a listener to
>   one of Symfony's core events, you can flag it with the
>   kernel.event_listener tag.

Tags are treated specially so that when the service container is "compiled" certain classes may be able to make a second "compiler pass" and act on services that are tagged.

See the Symfony2 documentation for more details about compiler passes: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#components-di-separate-compiler-passes

Answer (score 0):

1.) RedirectRepository is not a Drupal core functionality please specify contrib module name or provide code in order to be able to respond to your question.

2.) The arguments in services mean that the are put as dependency an can be directly injected via the __constructor method of your service. No you cannot mention no table name here! Only services! You need to define a custom entity and service!

3.) A name to identify groups of services. Tags are used in compiler passes and for collecting cache bins. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html
What do you want to achieve with the tags?